# How to create v-models dyanmically in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm relatively new to Vue and using VueJS 2 latest build.

I'm getting a set of data from the database, something similar to this:

```
{
    count: 3,
    options: {
        'red': 10,
        'blue': 20,
        'green': 30,
        'yellow': 40
    }
}
```

I want to create a number of select dropdowns based on the value of `count` (in this case 3, but it could be any number).

In each select dropdown I want to display the `options` and adding v-model to them (and to Vue's `data` object) dynamically based on how many select boxes we have to create.

Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work, because I don't know where/how to bind the v-model dynamically.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select v-for="(c, index) in count" v-model="models[index]" :key="index">
            <option v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
                {{ option }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            count: 3,
            options: {
                red: 10,
                blue: 20,
                green: 30,
                yellow: 40,
            },
            models: []
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

What is the best way to bind the values to data with v-models dynamically? If you need anything else, just let me know.

Comment: One possible way to do it is to fill the `models` array with as many NULLs as is the value of `count` - and then bind the `v-model` of each SELECT to the corresponding element in the `models` array.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using components...

create a component called: `dropdown.vue //anything you wan to name it`

```
//dropdown.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <select :key="index" @change="emitChange">
            <option v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
                {{ option }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Dropdown',
    model: {
        prop: 'value',
        event: 'change'
    },
    props: {
        value: String
    },
    //props: ['options', 'key'],
    /*data() {
        selectValue: "", //option selected value
    }, */

    methods: {
        emitChange() {
            this.$emit('change', $event.target.value)
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Now in your child you can:
**Edit: Now your components is like a select box with custom v-model**

```
<template>
    <template v-for="(c, index) in count">
        <Dropdown v-model="selectedOption" :index="index" :items="options" />
    </template>
</template>

<script>
import Dropdown from 'path/to/components/dropdown'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selectedOption: "",
            count: 3,
            options: {
                red: 10,
                blue: 20,
                green: 30,
                yellow: 40,
            },
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Now you can perform action with the v-model in the components...

**Edit:** I have modified the components to acts as dropdown with custom v-model.

Comment: Thank you it sounds like an interesting way of doing it. How could I use those v-model values in my Parent component then? Let's say I want to store them in an array/object in the parent component. How would I do that?

Comment: If you want to access all the v-model values in one place, then it will be a good move to use vuex to manage the data... Does it answer your question?

Comment: I simply want to use it one component where I'm creating all those small select dropdown components. If possible I wouldn't use Vuex, it's designed to be a pretty small app.